# How to solve the pointer issue in the double linked list below?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Recently I learnt about doubly linked lists, and I have tried to write some code in C to implement them. The program below is supposed to receive integer inputs form the user and put them into a list with a maximum of ten integers. However, when I input the values and then print them, only the first and last values are output. How would one solve this issue?
Here is the code:

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node {
    struct node* prev;
    int num;
    struct node* next;

};


struct node *head,*p;
struct node* create_first_node(int x)
{
    struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->num=x;
    new->prev=NULL;
    new->next=NULL;
    head=new;
    p=head;
    return new;
}
void add_node(int x)
 {
    struct node*new=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->num=x;
    new->prev=p;
    p->next=new;
    (new->next)=NULL;
    new=p;
 }

 void print_list(){
    struct node *temp= head;
    printf("\nThe list is:\n");
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",temp->num);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    int in[10];
    int len,i;
    head=NULL;
    
    printf("How many nodes would you like?(Max=10) \n");
    scanf("%d",&len);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
         if (head == NULL && i==0)
        {   
            printf("Enter Value for node %d\n",i+1);
            scanf("%d",(in+i));
            create_first_node(in[0]); 
           
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Enter Value for node %d\n",i+1);
                scanf("%d",(in+i));
                add_node(in[i]);
        }
        
    }
    
   
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: You probably mean `p=new` instead of `new=p` in `add_node`?

Comment: In your `add_node` you have `new=p;`. You probably meant `p=new` instead.

Comment: And please rename `p` to `tail` to make it clearer what's happening.

Comment: Typically, debugging and/or logging is used to solve such issues.

Comment: What's the point of `return new` in `create_first_node()`? It's unnecessary!